# Expected to find ' , ' (dart issue)

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

As I try to add "as String" in line 68, it gives me this error

Don't understand where I'm missing the comma

I tried removing the "as String" but still no benefit, the course im following along has suggested me to do this

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Copy your code and put it into the snipped code

Comment: Also, we'd need the code for `Question`to help you :/

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm a totally new to the dev community and this is my first post, ill make sure to follow these guidelines moving forward

Comment: Please do more research online before resolving to asking stack-overflow.  Check out flutter.dev for documentation or search similar questions first.

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String
```

Comment: `questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'].toString()` will also work